# Routes on Rails application are failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm taking an MOOC and the goal of this exercise is to add a new functionality to typo, where i can merge two articles together.

When I add the route to my new function merge to the routes.rb I'm losing the functionality to delete articles. I think something clashes here, but I have no idea what.

The original routes.rb:

```
%w{advanced cache categories comments content profiles feedback general pages
resources sidebar textfilters themes trackbacks users settings tags redirects seo post_types }.each do |i|
  match "/admin/#{i}", :to => "admin/#{i}#index", :format => false
  match "/admin/#{i}(/:action(/:id))", :to => "admin/#{i}", :action => nil, :id => nil, :format => false
end
```

This method in articles.rb creates the correct url for deleting

```
def delete_url
 blog.url_for(:controller => "/admin/content", :action =>"destroy",:id => id)
end
```

correct url:

```
http://example.com/admin/content/destroy/7
```

If i follow this link i can successfully delete an article.

However, if I add the following before that to my routes.rb:

```
namespace "admin" do
 resources :content do
   post :merge, on: :member, as: :merge
 end
end
```

The new merging functionality and forms are working fine, but the method `delete_url` now produces something like this:

```
http://example.com/admin/content/7
```

and if I follow a link created by this method i get:

```
Unknown action

The action 'show' could not be found for Admin::ContentController
```

Maybe I'm overwriting something? I can't figure out what's happening here and why this affects the delete action / route.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: rake routes | grep content:

with the original routes.rb gives me:

```
admin_content        /admin/content                     {:controller=>"admin/content", :action=>"index"}
                     /admin/content(/:action(/:id))     {:action=>nil, :id=>nil, :controller=>"admin/content"}
```

whereas my modified routes.rb produces

```
merge_admin_content POST   /admin/content/:id/merge(.:format) {:action=>"merge", :controller=>"admin/content"}
admin_content_index GET    /admin/content(.:format)           {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/content"}
                   POST   /admin/content(.:format)           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"admin/content"}
 new_admin_content GET    /admin/content/new(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/content"}
edit_admin_content GET    /admin/content/:id/edit(.:format)  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/content"}
     admin_content GET    /admin/content/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/content"}
                   PUT    /admin/content/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/content"}
                   DELETE /admin/content/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"admin/content"}
                          /admin/content                     {:controller=>"admin/content", :action=>"index"}
                          /admin/content(/:action(/:id))     {:action=>nil, :id=>nil, :controller=>"admin/content"}
```

Comment: Can you post your actual link?  I.e. your `link_to` where you call `delete_url`  I suspect you just need to add `method: :delete` to it.

Comment: Also, could you post the output of running `rake routes | grep content`? Also, `admin/content_controller.rb` would be helpful for us to see.

Answer (score 0):

Check `rake routes` command. I think there is a route `/admin/content/:id` which will be created by `resources :content` in the `namespace "admin"`. 
Your request to `http://example.com/admin/content/7` will be catched be the defined route but I gess you have no show action in the controller.

Better:

```
namespace "admin" do
  post "/content/:id/merge", to: "admin/content#merge", as: :merge
end
```

For more information about recources and the CRUD operations please see the [rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).

Comment: You are right!
i thought this would just create a route for ` admin/content/:id/merge ` 
(see my edited orginal post for the output of rake routes) 

also there is no show action... 
Is there a workaround, so that i just create a route for the merge?

Comment: Yes, there is: `resources :content, except: [:index, :show, :update, :destroy, :edit, :new, :create]`

Comment: But I would just put a `post "/content/:id/merge", to: "admin/content#merge", as: :merge` into the namespace instead of the resources variant, because it seems you don't need the other routes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks to @guitarman i worked through my routes code and found out I can add the following `except`:

```
namespace "admin" do
 resources :content, except: [:index, :show, :update, :destroy, :edit, :new, :create] do
   post :merge, on: :member, as: :merge
 end
end
```

after that, the rake routes just shows the additional merge route I wanted and my destroy action works fine again.